# Memory Management Headache

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I get leaks if I dont put it in dealloc.  I get a crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` If I do.  I cannot see anything wrong with this code.  The bad access is pointed at `[events release]`.  Have I made a mistake in the code below or is Instruments just having a laugh at my expense?

`events` is an `NSArray`

```
@interface EventsViewController : UITableViewController 
{    
@private
    NSArray *events;
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        events = [[self getEvents] retain];
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [events release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (NSArray*)getEvents
    {
        NSMutableArray *response = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

       //Some sql
       while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
       {
           Event *event = [[[Event alloc] init] autorelease];
           event.subject = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

          [response addObject:event];
       }
       return response;
    }
```

**Update**
A lot of you are saying the code is fine which is a plus.  I dont manipulate `events` elsewhere - I have removed any code that does to try and single out the crash.  Perhaps its in the parent view?

This is the click event that pushes the EventsViewController:
- (void)eventsClick:(id)sender

```
{
    EventsViewController *eventsViewController = [[EventsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventsViewController" bundle:nil];
    eventsViewController.anywhereConnection = anywhereConnection;
    eventsViewController.contact = contact;

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:eventsViewController animated:YES];
    [eventsViewController release];
}
```

The crash is actually happening when I return to the parent view.  (I think it is considered a parent in this scenario).   But perhaps the `[eventsViewController release]` just triggers `dealloc` in the `EventViewController`.

Comment: There is no mistake in that code. Please post more of your code.. probably you alter the member variable events on another point in the code?

Comment: Coding conventions specify that only methods that return results vis reference parameters should have the prefix "get". To do otherwise causes confusion.

Comment: How is `events` declared, is it a property, if so please provide the code. ALso, strongly consider using ARC.

Comment: events is not a property just a variable.  Good point about "get" that was lazy on my part.  I'll post some more code.

Comment: Did do you try to enbale NSZombies ?

Comment: I did try Zombies and It/I didn't find anything :(

Comment: How is the `subject` property of `Event` declared?

Comment: Please show the code where `events` is declared and instantiated.

Comment: @ade setting events to nil in the dealloc is working!!! - well it certainly appears to be on first look if you want to add it as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try putting

```
events = nil;
```

in dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just refactoring your code to use ARC? It works with iOS 4 and up and will make your life a lot easier. There are plenty of tutorials out there that will guide you how to do it, and will remove the need to manually figure out the nuances of memory management.

Comment: Hey, this ARC stuff looks pretty good.  I waste far too much time wrapping my head around memory management problems.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

If your Events object has property 'subject' set as assign, then the results of stringWithUTF8String: will not be retained. (Same thing if Events is a C++ object.)

The stringWithUTF8String: method returns an auto-released object that will be released at the next turn of the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference when you reference a variable via "self", and when you don't.

When you use

```
events = [[self getEvents] retain];
```

the memory allocated in getEvents never gets stored in the class property and is basically a leak.

You need to use

```
self.events = [self getEvents]; // no need to use retain if property is correctly defined.
```

Then

```
[events release];
```

should work fine.